# Table Layout not showing & getChildCount caused exception, android

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I experiment with the table layout using one of the documented examples.  With a barebone `MainActivity` that just has the following code up to `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)`, the emulator showed the table layout fine.  I then added the lines after the `setContentView` line and that action caused :

1. the layout not showing in the emulator (even after executing passed
   the setContentView line, when the code stopped at a breakpoint on
   the tableLayout declaration line)
2. error at the line with the first `getChildCount()`.

### The code in the MainActivity is shown below:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    TableLayout tableLayout = null;
    int s = tableLayout.getChildCount(); 

    for(int n = 0; n < s; ++n) {
        TableRow row = (TableRow)tableLayout.getChildAt(n);
        int t = row.getChildCount();
```

### }

What have I missed?  Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: If the `tableLayout` reference is `null` what exactly do you expect to happen when you're calling the `getChildCount` on this `null` reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to initialise your `TableLayout tableLayout` like this:

```
TableLayout tableLayout = findViewById(R.id.whatever_id_you_gave_to_the_tablelayout);
```

Comment: Thanks to all responses.  I was wondering myself. I copied the code from another blog which actually set the tablelayout to null before calling get child().  I thought this was some android special but I must have misunderstood something.

Comment: I suppose the layout not showing on emulator with the bug was because the setcontentview() spawn a separate thread and did not get to show the layout before the emulator was stopped by the bug?

Answer (score 0):

As Luksprog said, tableLayout is null , so how would you get getChildCount for a null value.Hence assign it with a value.

```
TableLayout tableLayout = findViewById(R.id.your_table_layout_id);
```

Here your_table_layout_id is the id you gave your table layout in the xml file.